# Problems changing Value in TextInput when using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this class that shows two TextInputs, initially the values are empty but then another component send the values by props. The problem is that I also want to edit them in this component but its not working properly. After receiving the values and changing them, then if i want to copy the password with the Button and paste it theres nothing, doesnt copy the value. The weird thing is that its copying the user correctly although I remember yesterday it happened the opposite (was copying the password). I added a userInitialized and passInitialized booleans that are set to true if the values are changed by typing and not for passing props. Any idea? Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Clipboard, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class BotomQRScanner extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userField: this.props.user,
            userInitialized: false,
            passInitialized: false,
            passwordField: this.props.pass
        }
    }

    handleUserChange = value => {
    this.setState({userField: value, userInitialized: true});
  }

    handlePasswordChange = value => {
    this.setState({passwordField: value, passInitialized: true});
  }

    render(){

        return (
            <View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>

                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <TextInput
                onChangeText={(value) => this.handleUserChange(value)}
                style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16, height: 50, width: 200}}
                autoCapitalize = 'none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                selectTextOnFocus={true}
                placeholder={'username'}
                selectionColor={'#428AF8'}
                value={this.state.userInitialized? this.state.userField : this.props.user}
              />
              <Button
              title="copy"
              onPress={() => {
              Clipboard.setString(this.state.userInitialized? this.state.userField : this.props.user)
            }}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <TextInput
                onChangeText={(value) => this.handlePasswordChange(value)}
                style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16, height: 80, width: 200}}
                autoCapitalize = 'none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                selectTextOnFocus={true}
                placeholder={'password'}
                value={this.state.passInitialized? this.state.passField : this.props.pass}
              />
              <Button
              title="copy"
              onPress={() => {
              Clipboard.setString(this.state.passInitialized? this.state.passField : this.props.pass)
            }}
            />
          </View>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logo: {
        width: 80,
        height: 26,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    container: {
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    right: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed variable names in your code:

```
Clipboard.setString(this.state.passInitialized? this.state.passField : this.props.pass)
```

here you use `passField` but in your state you declared `passwordField`
Here's a working sandbox with your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hill-4widm

Comment: oh thank you man! Works better indeed! I only have a new problem now doing the following: ```1. I write down manually in the inputs 2. I send from props the new values 3. The text inputs dont show the new values```